# AWS Batch - Not authorized to use launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-batch

I'm trying to change the [allocation_strategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/allocation-strategies.html) of my [aws_batch_compute_environment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/batch_compute_environment) from `BEST_FIT`(default) to `BEST_FIT_PROGRESSIVE`.
However my jobs get stuck in `RUNNABLE` after I make this change and the compute_environment status also changes to `INVALID` and status_reason `CLIENT_ERROR - You are not authorized to use launch template Batch-lt-uuid`.

I went through the discussion [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/batch-invalid-compute-environment), and I don't think my [AWSBatchServiceRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html) should be an issue since I'm using a slightly modified version of the AWS recommended policy. However I haven't checked if any SCPs are blocking access (Still I don't understand why `BEST_FIT_PROGRESSIVE` would cause this issue when everything works good with `BEST_FIT`)

I observed that the launch templates created automatically by AWS Batch don't propagate AWS Batch tags, so I also tried to create my own launch_template and add it under the `compute_resources` of `aws_batch_compute_environment`. However AWS Batch soon reattaches a launch template of its own and doesn't use the one I added in the configuration. My user_data differs slightly from the one automatically created by AWS Batch in that, I don't specify the ECS cluster name since we only get to know this after the creation of the `compute_environment`.

My user data

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==BOUNDARY=="
MIME-Version: 1.0

--==BOUNDARY==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ecs_cluster_name}>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_DISABLE_IMAGE_CLEANUP=false>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_ENGINE_TASK_CLEANUP_WAIT_DURATION=2m>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_IMAGE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL=10m>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_IMAGE_MINIMUM_CLEANUP_AGE=10m>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_NUM_IMAGES_DELETE_PER_CYCLE=5>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_RESERVED_MEMORY=32>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
echo ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES={\"com.amazonaws.batch.compute-environment-revision\":\"0\"}>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config
--==BOUNDARY==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=${ecs_cluster_name}>>/etc/ecs/ecs.config

--==BOUNDARY==--
```

I'd love to hear your ideas and suggestions of what I'm missing here, and stuff I can try out. Thank you!

Comment: AWS Batch uses your launch template as a base to create a new one when the compute environment is created ([or during an infrastructure update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/updating-compute-environments.html)).  Infra updates are only possible when you use the [service-linked role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/service_IAM_role.html). User-defined roles are not supported since we can't guarantee that the role will change during the update process, or after, causing the CE to go invalid.

Comment: I would create a new CE with what you require and move the job queue to using it.